# how can I compare two values in inheritance in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to create a program that checks which account have lowest cost, but I don't know how to implement this in my program.

I want to select the output of each class  separately to compare `(dayTimeCost)`

This is what I think it may be implemted but I don't know how

> if (BronceDayTimeCost < SilverDayTimeCost){ System.out.print("\nThe Bronze Account is cheapest.");}
>
> if (SilverDayTimeCost< BronceDayTimeCost ){ System.out.print("\nThe Silver Account is cheapest.");}

**Bronze Class**

```
    public  class Bronze  {

    // ----------------- Atributes -----------------------

    

    public int dayMinutes;      // daytime telphone minutes used

    public double dayTimeCost;  //Total daytime calls cost

    // ------------- CONSTRUCTORS (inputs) ---------------

    public Bronze(int theDayMinutes ) {  
    dayMinutes = theDayMinutes; 
    }
    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------
    // Calculate Total daytime calls cost
    public double calcDayTimeCost(double costDay) {

        dayTimeCost = dayMinutes * costDay;
        System.out.print("\nCost of daytime calls = "  + costDay + "/min"+
        "\n\nTotal daytime calls cost = " + dayTimeCost + 
        "\n");

        return dayTimeCost;
    }

    //toString method to override that in Object
    public String toString(){
    return(
 "\n" 
         );
    }

    //Returns the type of account
    public String type(){
    return "Bronze";
    }
}
```

**Silver Class**

```
   public class Silver extends Bronze {

    private static final double costDay = 0.22;

    public Silver(int theDayMinutes ) {
    super(theDayMinutes );

  }
    //Returns the type of account
    public String type(){
    return "Silver";
    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountUser {

    // ------------------- FIELDS ------------------------    

    // Create instance of Scanner class
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // variables
    public static Bronze bron;
    public static Silver silv;

    public static int dayMinutes;

    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------  

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // Input dayMinutes (with error message)
        do{
        System.out.print("Please daytime telphone minutes used --> ");
        dayMinutes  = input.nextInt();
        if  ( dayMinutes <= 0){System.out.print("\n" + "Input value outside the range!!!" + "\n");}
        }while( dayMinutes <= 0);


        // Create new Bronze instance
        bron = new Bronze(dayMinutes);
        silv = new Silver(dayMinutes);
        // Calculate scheme1, scheme2
        bron.calcDayTimeCost(0.12);
        silv.calcDayTimeCost(0.22);


    System.out.println(bron);
    System.out.println(silv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You should read more about inheritance. Silver shouldn't inherit from Bronze. Rather it should inherit. (For the sake of demonstration rather than need) from something more abstract, like level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the `return` type of `calcDayTimeCost` method into a `double` variable as shown below and then check which cost is lower using an `if` and `else` conditions.

```
double bronCost = bron.calcDayTimeCost(0.12);
double silverCost = silv.calcDayTimeCost(0.22);
if(bronCost == silverCost) {
    System.out.print("\nThe Silver and Bronze Accounts are same cost ");
} else if (bronCost < silverCost){ 
     System.out.print("\nThe Bronze Account is cheapest.");
} else {
     System.out.print("\nThe Silver Account is cheapest.");
}
```

Although your code works, it is not inline with Object Oriented Programming i.e., in general, we create classes inline with the real world objects, but `Bronze` and `Silver` two different elements i.e., they don't directly relate/inherit each other.

In other words, when you say `ClassA` `extends` `ClassB`, you are saying that `ClassA` IS-A `ClassB`

So, the alternative approach to this is as follows:

```
  public abstract class Metal {

        //add fields applicable for all metals  

        public double calcDayTimeCost() {
             //add code here
        }
    }

  public class Bronze extends Metal {

       //Bronze specific details
  }

  public class Silver extends Metal {

       //Silver specific details
  }
```